# How can i return images from assets instead of systemName Image and call it in the body Using swiftui

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, switch-statement

How can i return images from assets instead of systemName Image   and call it in the body Using swiftui

```
var sfSymbol: String {
        switch self {
        case .info:
         return "info.circle"
        case .success:
            return "checkmark.seal"
        case .warning:
            return "exclamationmark.octagon"
        case .error:
            return "xmark.octagon"
        }
    }

 Image.init(systemName: data.type.sfSymbol)
```

Comment: in my code i use switch statement to return icons if success i use the icon "checkmark.seal" if info i use the icon "info.circle" but this icons are not my own images . they are a systemName Image  and i want to use my own images in the assets not the systemName image and i don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an `Image Set`, an `@ViewBuilder`.

```
struct CustomImageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Symbols.info.image()
    }
    enum Symbols: String, CaseIterable{
        case info
        case success
        case warning
        case error
        var sfSymbolName: String{
            switch self {
            case .info:
                return "info.circle"
            case .success:
                return "checkmark.seal"
            case .warning:
                return "exclamationmark.octagon"
            case .error:
                return "xmark.octagon"
            }
        }
        ///Name must exactly match an `Image Set` in `Assets`
        ///Project Navigator > Assets > + > Image Set >
        var assetsName: String{
            switch self {
            case .info:
                return "NameFromAssetsImageSet_info"
            case .success:
                return "NameFromAssetsImageSet_success"
            case .warning:
                return "NameFromAssetsImageSet_warning"
            case .error:
                return "NameFromAssetsImageSet_error"
            }
        }
        
        @ViewBuilder func image() -> some View {
            let showFromAssets: Bool = true
            switch showFromAssets{
            case true:
                Image(assetsName)
            case false:
                Image(systemName: sfSymbolName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `asset images`, you have to use `Image("")` not `Image(systemName: "")` because the **Image(systemName: "")** is for `SF Symbols`.

Say your image in the asset with name "Swift", just call it like this in your body:

```
Image("Swift")
```

or

```
Image(myStringVariable)
```

**myStringVariable** is a @State var that you set its value depends on the given condition